# Aesthetics error

Tags: r, shiny

I have problem in plot (R Studio + Shiny).

Error:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7444
>       Warning: Error in : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): x, y, colour
>       Stack trace (innermost first):
>           68: output$plot6th
>            1: runApp

Script/App:

```
https://github.com/futer/japan_telecom/
```

On ReadMe is how to lunch.

And second question...
I have made 6 action button, but I dont know how make thing :
Click on button 1 and only plot 1 is showed etc...

I will be glad if someone help me.

Comment: Please reduce this to something sufficiently minimal that it can be wholly shown within the question while still being self contained and reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to generating the chart is wrong; you should transform the data.frame to a long format and then generate the chart. As the whole app is too big to post here, I've prepared the extract how you should approach the data frame you want to handle:

```
Vectorize(require)(package = c("dplyr", "tidyr", "ggplot2", "zoo"),
                   character.only = TRUE)

# Sourced from within the app
df %>% 
  gather(key = indicator, value = value, -Date) %>% 
  # Scale is just an example
  mutate(valueScld = scale(value)) %>% 
  # Chart definition
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, group = indicator, colour = indicator)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 years") +
  geom_line()
```

Then you will start getting to something that resembles the desired chart:

### [image]

*I would further suggest that you have a look at [this basic article](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/) on generating graphs in `ggplot2`; after transforming your data frame handling aesthetics will be simple. In your code you have `geom_line` defined **x** number of times, each for each group which is not the way to go.*